# jQuery File Upload response does not contain jqXHR.responseText property in IE < 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, jquery-file-upload

I'm getting some trouble with ie8/ie9 while trying to get response Html from server.

```
$(function() {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: '@Url.Action("Save", "CounterDoc")',
        dataType: 'json',
        formData: window.globalParams, 
        fail: function (e, data) { // case when server returns NOT JSON - is fail.                 
            var responseObj = {};
            responseObj.responseText = data.response().jqXHR.responseText;
        }
    });
});
```

Here data.response().jqXHR.responseText is always undefined in old Ies. What am I doing wrong? Can i get response body in old browsers?

Comment: Can you confirm which file upload plugin you're using? It sounds likely to be a problem with the plugin; maybe it doesn't support old IE versions?

Comment: @Spudley I'm using blueimp jquery file upload. And description says it has support of old ies starting from ie6. I admit, that ie8 does not have xhr support, and that causes my problem. But i still have a question: "Can i somehow get response body of my ajax request from "data" or else?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer in [FAQ](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#does-the-plugin-support-http-status-codes):

As ie<10 version uses iframe to send-receive data instead of xhr response body is not accessible in usual way. So for ie I have to override converters to throw error if server responded with invalid data type.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        converters: {
            'iframe json': function (iframe) {

                var result = {};
                result.responseText = iframe && $(iframe[0].body)[0].innerHTML;

                if (!IsJsonString(result.responseText)) { // answer IS NOT JSON, html contains error data

                    throw result;
                }
                else { // server sent valid JSON - OK
                    return $.parseJSON(result);    
                }
            }
        }
    });
```